# Blank popup screen for Microsoft signin

Tags: windows-10, login-screen

Microsoft sign in popup appears blank on any product in Windows 10; OneNote, Visual Studio, Yammer, etc..
However the same works on their respective websites.
How do I sign in to Microsoft account now?

[image: Signin Popup screen is blank is multiple Microsoft products]

Comment: So what exactly is your question?  Have you linked your local account to your Microsoft Account by chance?

Comment: How to link local account with Microsoft account, can you help?

Comment: Have you researched the subject, it's in settings...

Comment: Searched on Google ... found this ...
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/wiki/insider_wintp-insider_security/how-to-connect-to-a-microsoft-account-in-windows/c1614fe6-a9cd-4723-a9e0-7293d9cdfd4a

My microsoft account shows up in Windows 10 Accounts settings.

However, the problem is that when I use some Microsoft products, i need to explicitely sign in to my microsoft account to sync my data and other stuffs. **Here is the problem**. The sign in popup remains blank as shown in in the picture above